# Does a variable with transient property gets assigned with value if JSON string has that variable?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, transient

I'm not very familiar with serializations especially in relation to transient property so I want to know whether a variable with transient property gets assigned with a value if the JSON string being serialized contains that keyword/variable with corresponding value.

lets say I have a JSON:

> "json": { "title": "TEST", "date": "2015-07-20" }

and I have a class:

```
public class MyClass {
    protected String title;
    protected transient String date;
}
```

will the variable **date** receive the value of *date* in the JSON when I use GSON's fromJson() method?

**EDIT**: just to clear things out, I don't plan to use the GsonBuilder, just the default settings it has. I just really wanna know about how it handles my stated case

Comment: just curious: why did you accept the answer which is correct in most cases, but still incomplete?

Comment: @wero: I was able to get approximately the same answer from both of you, you just pointed out that it is **possible** to include the transient variable by using the GsonBuilder but I was only asking whether the value will get assigned to the transient variable or not. A simple yes or no question, I just wasn't able to mention that I'll be using the default Gson not the GsonBuilder for the gson object. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no it will not. From the the documentation

> if a field is marked transient, (by default) it is ignored and not
>   included in the JSON serialization or deserialization.

you can find it [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

Answer (score 1):

By default it is ignored. From the [docs](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide):

> If a field is marked transient, (by default) it is ignored and not
>   included in the JSON serialization or deserialization.

But you can change that default behaviour by constructing a special `Gson` object:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
   .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.STATIC)
   .create();
```

which will include transient fields.